# How can I set criteria on $wp_list_table->display()

Tags: wordpress

I don't want to list all pages when I click on pages. I find that wordpress use $wp_list_table->display() to display all data.
But How can I set criteria on it?
Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pre_get_posts` to modify admin queries. Here's an example that limits the query to some specific page IDs:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'so27531690_pre_get_posts' );
function so27531690_pre_get_posts( $query )
{
    if( ! ( is_admin() && 'edit-page' == $GLOBALS['current_screen']->id ) )
        return;

    $query->set( 'post__in', array( 1,6,15 ) );

    return;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a new wordpress . where should I execute the above code?

Comment: I have create one field called 'custom' in wp_posts table. Can I query base on it?  $query->set('custom',123);